# Job Runner service unable to start due to logon failure

Tags: powershell

I'm working with PowerShell and I need to start job runner automatically once 
  my script is run but getting an exception like "Unable to start service due to 
  logon failure".

Can anyone help me how can I resolve that error?

```
function ServiceStart($ServiceName){
    try
    {
    Write-Host $("Starting service " + $ServiceName)
    $timeout = [System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(5)

    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    if ($arrService -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host $("**ERROR** No service named '" + $ServiceName + "' 
    found")
        return $false
    }
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 
    [ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running)
    {
        return $true
    }
    $arrService.Start()
    try
    {

    $arrService.WaitForStatus([ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]
    ::Running, $timeout)
    }
    catch [ServiceProcess.TimeoutException]
    {
        Write-Verbose "Timeout starting service $($arrService.Name)"
        throw "Timeout starting service $($arrService.Name)"
    }
    Write-Host $("Started service " + $ServiceName)
    return $true
    }
    catch
    {
    Write-Host $("**ERROR** Unable to start service '$ServiceName'. 
    Exception: " + $_.Exception.Message + ". InnerException: " + 
    $_.Exception.InnerException)
    throw $("**ERROR** Unable to start service '$ServiceName'. Exception: " 
    + $_.Exception.Message + ". InnerException: " + 
    $_.Exception.InnerException)
    }
```

Comment: First, read the error message.

Comment: I have understood the error. If I go and log in manually it's working But, I want my service to log in automatically

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem.